# "To do" or "For doing"

Tags: meaning

I recently came across a person saying,

> I need to make money for paying my bills.

This puzzled me, because I would normally use "to pay". I've come across other uses on the Internet where people said

> I need the ingredients for making a cake.

Instead of

> I need the ingredients to make a cake.

Can someone explain to me the difference in meaning and how to correctly use both of these?

Comment: I think they are equivalent, however I feel **to** shows the intention, while **for** shows the application, then **to** is more appropriate  for paying, and **for** better **for making a cake**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my "gut feeling" only, I don't have any rule or example to support it.

The difference between

> I need to make money **for paying** my bills.

and

> I need to make money **to pay** my bills.

is subtle but discernable.

The former identifies an activity (paying bills) and speaks of the need to make money as a prerequisite.  As if, "among other things I have this 'bill paying' thing that I can do, and the money is required for that, so I need to make it".

The latter puts bill paying to the forefront, so to speak, as if there is nothing else.  Again, money making is a prerequisite but the repetition of '***to***' puts a stress on the actions, draws them into the limelight.

"***For paying my bills***" does not indicate it as a priority.  Just another purpose among so many, of making money.  "***To pay my bills***" speaks to me of urgency, of vital importance.

Same notion with the **cake**.

> I need the ingredients ***for making*** a cake.

Basically says that if some cake ingredients happen to be around, I'll take them.  I might make a cake with those, or might just put it in my pocket book.

> I need the ingredients ***to make*** a cake.

Says that I *am going to make a cake* and ingredients are wanted.